# TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable

Tags: python, authentication, pyqt4, basic-authentication, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm trying to make a request to a protected webpage, so therefore I'm trying to authenticate with help from `QAuthenticator()`. However, I get the following error:

```
mgr.authenticationRequired(response, auth)
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

This is a part of my script:

```
def authenticate(self):
    username = 'user'
    password = 'pass'
    url = 'http://someurl.com'

    mgr = QNetworkAccessManager(self)

    auth = QAuthenticator()
    auth.setUser(username)
    auth.setPassword(password)

    response = QNetworkRequest()
    response.setUrl(QUrl(url))     

    mgr.authenticationRequired(mgr.get(response), auth)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

As the error message indicates, you cannot call PyQt signals.  Instead, you have to use the `emit()` method:

```
mgr.authenticationRequired.emit(mgr.get(response), auth)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to emit the signal?  My understanding of the protocol is that the QNAM will emit that signal when a server across the network wants authentication.  Your program should connect to that signal, not emit it.  "The slot connected to this signal should fill the credentials for the contents (which can be determined by inspecting the reply object) in the authenticator object."  I could be wrong about what you are attempting.